# How to extract value based on the header OR how to extract headers value from ods file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, roo, ruby-roo

[image]

Want to extract values under "Location" header.

EDIT: —-following extracted from following comments.  It originally appeared this was a web related thing, but no, the OP is dealing with a spreadsheet, not a web page.)—-

This is an excel sheet and I want to extract the table values based on the header.

For Example :

xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('Demo.xls') values_under_headers = values_of("Location")

Something same which gives values from 1007,1008,1009.....

Comment: Hey, provide the html man! How come people know the structure of the html if you only post the picture?

Comment: Show us the HTML for that part of the page, and the code you have that isn’t working.  We can’t tell the HTML from a screenshot, nor can we read your mind to know what you’ve tried so far.   If you want help you need to give us something to work with.

Comment: SHOW US THE CODE YOU HAVE TRIED SO FAR.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code for what?
This is an excel sheet and I want to extract the table values based on the header.

For Example :

xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('Demo.xls')
values_under_headers = values_of("Location")

Something same which gives values from 1007,1008,1009.....

Comment: If this isn’t a browser based task why are you trying to use watir?  The W in watir stands for web, it’s for driving web browsers and testing web apps.   I’m removing the watir tag from this question as apparently it is in no way web browser related

Comment: This is not directly connected to watir. I have been uing watir since 4 years. The only reason was , If people who do automation using watir may have same thing sorted in past